# Empty Cursor query MediaStore.Images.Media

Tags: android

I try to get a cursor with ALL the images provided by MediaStore.Images.Media with a contentResolver, but the cursor is empty ! (I tried it on my phone with lots of images). The code is :

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadPicture);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, filePathColumn, null,null,null);

            if(cursor.moveToFirst()==false) Log.i("my message","EMPTY");

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);


            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }
    });
}
```

Do you know how to have at least a not empty cursor? Thanks a lot

Comment: tried EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI?

Comment: it's for SD cards, not images inside the phone memory right?

Answer (score 1):

use `EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` instead of `INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, filePathColumn , null, null, null);
```

then you will have a cursor containing all the filepaths (MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

Comment: But EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI will not give me images in the phone memory, isn't it? EXTERNAL is about SD cards for example i thought...